# Excel Extract Text after different letters

Tags: microsoft-excel

So I'm trying to extract some text from cells in Excel but am having issues. Have tried searching but not really coming up with much and I can't edit any of my current formulas to get it working.

So I have a list of races that I'm trying to extract some information from to fill into other cells. After the : below it has the race length and then the race type and I'm trying to extract just the race type and fill it in another cell.

```
Carlisle 17th Aug : 1m Nov Stks
Leicester 17th Aug : 6f Nursery
Leicester 17th Aug : 6f Hcap
Carlisle 17th Aug : 1m Hcap
Sligo 17th Aug : 2m4f Hcap Hrd
Leicester 17th Aug : 1m Hcap
```

Thought I'd cracked it with the below but then realised that some I need to be searching for  "f " and others I need to be searching for "m ". How would you search for two different patterns in the text?

```
=MID(B2,FIND("f ",B2)+2,256)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the layout of your text, I think you need to anchor your search on the colon character. There are three pieces required to then find everything after the distance and this should work with pretty much every version of excel.

Assuming that the first race is in A2, you could put following formulae in C2,D2,E2. The first finds the offset of the ":" in the string, in this case 21 and adds 2 to get past the subsequent space. The second formula finds the offset of the next space in the remaining text (e.g. from 23 to end). The final formula then gets all the text from the last offset to the last character.

```
FIND(":",A3,1)+2
FIND(" ",A2,C2)
RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-D2)
```

The result for each formula is:

```
21  
23  
Nov Stks
```

To consolidate it into a single formula, put the following somewhere in row 3.

```
RIGHT(A3,LEN(A3)-FIND(" ",A3,FIND(":",A3,1)+2))
```

The result for A3 would be:

```
Nursery
```

And for all cells,

```
Nov Stks
Nursery
Hcap
Hcap
Hcap Hrd
Hcap
```

Comment: This worked great and thanks for the explanation.

Comment: Glad it helped. Regards.

Answer (score 1):

In `B1`, formula copied down :

```
=MID(A1,MIN(FIND({"f ","m "},A1&"f m "))+2,99)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this formula:
*=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-SEARCH(" ",A1,SEARCH(": ",A1)+2))*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This can easily be done with Power Query: First split by the semicolon, then split at the first space.

Or, you could copy the column, split by delimiter using the semicolon, then use a formula for the text left of the first space and another formula for the text right of the first space.

It's possible to get to this with one ugly nested formula. With Excel 365, you could use LET() to make the formula less complex.

If you don't state your Excel version, giving you the best formula for your scenario is hard.

Using LET()

```
=LET(TheRace,RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(":",A1&":")-1),RIGHT(TheRace,LEN(TheRace)-FIND(" ",TheRace&" ")))
```

[image]